# .txt file delete lines but keep the first 10?

Tags: php, if-statement, storage

How would I go about deleting lines in a .txt file? But keep the 1st ten lines?

Here is my code so far:

```
   <?php 

$hiScore = $_POST['hiScore'] ? $_POST['hiScore'] : 'not set';

$theInput = $_POST['theInput'] ? $_POST['theInput'] : 'not set';

$file = fopen('LeaderBoard.txt','a+');
fwrite($file, ' '.$hiScore.' - Score                                                      Name: '.$theInput.'      '.PHP_EOL);
fclose($file);

$lines = file("LeaderBoard.txt");
natsort($lines);
$lines=array_reverse($lines);
file_put_contents("LeaderBoardScores.txt", implode("\n  \n \n  \n  \n  \n \n  \n", $lines));

$handle = fopen("LeaderBoardScores.txt");
$output = '';
$i = 0;
while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    $output .= $line . "\n";
    if ($i++ >= 10)
        break;
}
fclose($handle);
file_put_contents($output, "Leader.txt");

?>
```

Im not sure how if staments work in PHP but maybe check the file and if lines = above 10 dont post anything to the file?

Score board the person sees: LeaderBoardScores.txt should only see the top 10

LeaderBoard.txt is where the data gets posted and then gets sorted for people to view in LeaderBoardScores.txt

Comment: User duplicated same question an hour later: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494839/php-read-a-txt-file-and-post-the-first-10-lines-to-a-new-txt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could loop through each line using `fgets()` and break out after the 10th line:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen($path_to_file);
$output = '';
$i = 0;
while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    $output .= $line . "\n";
    if ($i++ >= 10)
        break;
}
fclose($handle);
file_put_contents($output, $path_to_file);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php

In this case, `while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false)` loops through the lines in the existing file one-at-a-time. `$output` collects the content of the lines. `$i` counts how many lines we've added to `$output` so far so we can stop (`break`) at the right time.

Comment: How would I implement this into my already existing code? (Im really bad in php sorry for being stupid).

Comment: Thx for fixing the oversight, @OIS

Comment: @user3112634 You should maybe invest a *little* time in understanding this perfectly valid answer. Please do not resort to copy/paste programming. No one here would advocate it anyways.

Comment: @user3112634 You can pretty much just tack it on to the end of what you already have, just replace `$path_to_file` with the name of your text file.

Comment: @ Linus Kleen I think I sort of understand it, handle opens the file output is 'breakline' not to sure about the while part and if 'i' count is above 10 break the posting then close the file and then what file to put the 'stuff' in?

Comment: @user3112634 I added some detail below the code block, see if that helps.

Comment: Iv updated my code above i cant seem to get it to work for some reason it keeps posting and doesnt stop at 10, any idea's?

Comment: @user3112634 Hmmm... someone else edited my answer, try `$i++` instead of `++$i`. Updating answer now...

Comment: still seems to be posting more than 10

Comment: @user3112634 In the edits to your question above, you seem to have replaced `$path_to_file` with `$LeaderBoardScores.txt` - should be `'LeaderBoardScores.txt'` (quoted as a string, not $ as a variable)

Comment: I've also tried that could it be the 1st file_put_contents ? in the code

Comment: Could be. At this point, you'll have to step through it yourself to see where things break down. If you're not working in an IDE where you can add breakpoints to debug, the old-fashioned (hack?) way to do it is to run the code with `var_dump();` and `exit;` statements stopping execution at different points so you can inspect what's going on at each line.

Comment: I think iv cracked it just testing a little i think is was the 1st "put file contents"

Comment: Still cant get this to work the "sorting" of the file at the start of the code works but when adding to the code everything breaks and nothing is posted/ or posts most than 10

Comment: @user3112634, Stop with the asking neverending follow up questions and then editing your code in the question and asking more. This is not a debug service. Learn how to properly use the site.

Comment: @user3112634, Its called why questions like this should be closed as "please debug my code for me" demands. Learn to debug yourself: that's real learning. And save SO for real questions, not debug demands. The purpose of SO is for people in the future to learn from the questions. If you keep changing the code in the question and saying, "Ok, I edited the code, now please debug it" how will anyone in the future be able to follow the question?  They won't, because its no longer a question but a long debug process.